# PHP Random Number Loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a function that generates 20 random numbers:

```
function randomAttempts()
{
  $i=1;
      while($i<=20)
      {
          echo "The number is " . rand(1,100) . "<br>";
          $i++;
      }
}
```

However, my question is - how do I echo for example just the '10th' random number or the '11th' etc?

I think I'm missing the logic here.

Comment: Generate one random number, and call it the `10th` one.

Comment: Just add a conditional to only do the echo when $i equals your desired value. Voting to close as this question likely adds little value since the solution is so trivial.

Comment: Just add a simple condition inside the while loop like if($i==10) echo the number, else $i++

Comment: or echo the random(th) instead of the 10th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomAttempts($passNthNumberToBeEchoed)
{
  $i=1;
      while($i<=20)
      {
          $randNum =  rand(1,100);

          if($passNthNumberToBeEchoed==$i){
            echo "The number is " . $randNum  . "<br>";
            }

          $i++;
      }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution is like that:

```
function randomAttempts()
{
    $i=1;
    $printIndex = 11;
    while($i<=20)
    {
        if ($i == $printIndex)
            echo "The number is " . rand(1,100) . "<br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Or you can pass $printIndex as a parameter to your function

Edit:
There is no point to generate 20 numbers if you need lets say 11th.
Code like that would work better:

```
function randomAttempts($printIndex = 1)
{
    $i = 1;
    $random = 0;
    while($i<=$printIndex )
    {
        $random = rand(1,100);
        $i++;
    }
    echo "The number is " . $random . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Your if condition won't work. :)

Comment: @AshwinMukhija, yes, I put wrong number in the beginning. But it does not change the idea :)

Comment: That's true. I realized it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomAttempts($num)
{
  $i=1;
  $ar=array();
  while($i<=$num)
  {
      $ar[]=rand(1,100);
      $i++;
  }
  $out=array_pop($ar);
  unset($ar);
  return $out;
}
```

sample

```
echo randomAttempts(10);

echo randomAttempts(11);
```

Comment: Why to complicate it with array when you can simply save the value in int?

Comment: i want rand 10th or 11th i save all rand then get last yes can be down only by int but at first i wanted  to have all rand for that i use array

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but anyway every time you will call your function it will create a new array, fill it with data and return only the last one. Filling array is useless (as you are not using it in any other way, except returning the last value) and consumes more memory than int

Comment: yes it is correct.it  was  my mistake

Comment: @EvaldasDzimanavicius question? php didn't do unset variables  after return from function?

Comment: After return from the function php will set the array (and any other variables used only in function) for garbage collection as no references exist for it anymore. Off course it will not be instantly, as garbage collection runs from time to time, when necessary, but if your array is not huge, you should be fine without unsetting it.